# Matlab: Test the system is linear or not

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have an equation: `y(n) = a^x(n)`.

where `x1(n) ={0,1,2,3}, x2(n)={1,2,3,4}, a1=a2=1, a=2`.

So, How can i write MATLAB code to test the system is linear or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply [the definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_operator).

Consider a system S, such that the output to an input signal x(n) is S( x(n) ). S is linear if and only if

1. S( x1(n) + x2(n) ) = S( x1(n) ) + S( x2(n) ) for any inputs x1, x2 (*additivity*)
2. S( b * x1(n) ) = b * S( x1(n) ) for any input x1 and any number b (*homogeneity*)

In your case it's clear that neither 1 nor 2 hold, so the system y(n) = S( x(n) ) is not linear.

To test it with code: randomly generate many examples of `x1`, `x2` and `b` and check if the equalities above hold. Note that this way you will never be sure that the system *is* linear. You can only be sure it *isn't*, namely when you find `x1`, `x2`, `b` for which either 1 or 2 do not hold.

**Example**

```
>> a = 2; n = 3;
>> S = @(x) a*x.^n; %// anonymous function describing your system
>> x1 = 1:4; %// test input signal
>> x2 = 11:14; %// test input signal. Same length

>> S(x1)+S(x2)
ans =
        2664        3472        4448        5616

>> S(x1+x2)
ans =
        3456        5488        8192       11664
```

Since the results are different, the system does not satisfy property 1, and therefore it's not linear.

Comment: Hi, Can you try to answer this question, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748565/matlab-test-the-system-is-time-invariance-or-not